# Variable refering in two different jsp pages

Tags: java, jsp

If i declare a variable in my A.jsp and i am trying to include A.jsp to B.jsp.So my question stands here whether the variable declared in A.jsp is acessable in B.jsp?
Please explain me for both the cases Dynamic include and static include.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you include a jsp template using <%@page include=""> the source will actually be inserted and compiled into the including file. This is what makes you able to use variables declared in the parent file.

When doing a "dynamic" include it will use RequestDispatcher.include which will invoke the calling page as a new Servlet. This makes you unable to use declared variables.

I would recommend you to pass variables on the request scope using request.setAttribute("name", obj); when doing this

Answer (score 0):

You can't pass **server-side** parameters using the `<%@ include %>` directive. This directive does a static include. The contents of the included file are statically inserted into the including page. That is, during translation time from jsp to servlet.

Use the [`<jsp:include>`](http://java.sun.com/products/jsp/tags/11/syntaxref11.fm11.html) tag instead, it is processed at runtime, and with it you can pass parameters using `<jsp:param>`.

For instance, if you have a.jsp with

```
<jsp:include page="b.jsp" />
    <jsp:param name="param1" value="value1" />
    <jsp:param name="param2" value="value2" />
</jsp:include>
```

You can get those parameters as request parameters in b.jsp

```
<% String v = request.getParameter("param1"); %>
```

Take into account you can still get request parameters available on a.jsp in b.jsp.